# Unable to find the number of days between two dates when date format is dd-MMM-yyyy

Tags: java, android, validation, simpledateformat

I'm using the following code to parse two dates of type 23-May-2016 and 25-May-2017 then I'm trying to find the number days between both dates.

Following is the code that I'm using to do so,

```
SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Date validityDate = null;
Date nextDueDate = null;
try {
    validityDate = format1.parse(mValidity.getText().toString());
    nextDueDate = format2.parse(mDueDate.getText().toString());
    int validate = validate(validityDate, nextDueDate);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+validate,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

the `validate` method is as follows,

```
public static int validate(Date valid, Date nextDueDate) {
    return (int) ((nextDueDate.getTime() - valid.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24l));
}
```

When I'm trying to do so, I'm getting unable to parse at index offset 6.
How can I sort this out?

Comment: Please post your error log.

Comment: why you are multiplicating with 241 ? mustn´t it be 24?

Comment: this L looks like a one in that post.....and a Long value is not necessary here....

Comment: *`I'm getting unable to parse at index offset 6`* -- better add **the actual runtime error message** you are getting :-)

Comment: Remove that L from return (int) ((nextDueDate.getTime() - valid.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24l));  your code wors fine, i am getting 367 days as result in the toast. I think you need to check with your code it may be some other giving you error, Debug your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to use this code sample to change your `SimpleDateFormat` constructor call with the `Locale` specific version to make month string value (like "May") be parsable :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date validityDate = null;
Date nextDueDate = null;
try {
   validityDate = sdf.parse(mValidity.getText().toString());//string value like "25-May-2016"
   nextDueDate = sdf.parse(mDueDate.getText().toString());
   int validate = validate(validityDate, nextDueDate);
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+validate,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception ex) {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

also it is not necessary to create two identical `SimpleDateFormat` instances in your case

Answer (score 1):

// Get the Format first

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

// Define the Date

```
  Date d1 = new Date("01/01/2007 12:00:00");
  Date d2 = new Date("01/02/2007 12:00:00");
```

// Set the time

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();cal1.setTime(d1);
  Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();cal2.setTime(d2);
```

//Create this

```
 printOutput("Manual   ", d1, d2, calculateDays(d1, d2));
```

// Call

```
private static void printOutput(String type, Date d1, Date d2, long result) {
  System.out.println(type+ "- Days between: " + sdf.format(d1)
                    + " and " + sdf.format(d2) + " is: " + result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you can do something more simple, using the new Date and Time API:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse("23-May-2016", formatter);
    LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.parse("25-May-2017", formatter);
    System.out.println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2));
```

Comment: I suggest adding a call to `withLocale` on that formatter to explicitly define English as the language for parsing the name of month. `formatter = formatter.withLocale( Locale.ENGLISH );`